# TokenMismatchException in Edge and IE 11 with Laravel 5 App

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I have developed a laravel 5 app which is working well on all other browsers except IE and Edge. I am getting TokenMismatchException on all form submits. I read this blog https://robinz.in/csrf-token-session-error-with-laravel-on-ie-edge/

and implemented the following as an attempt to solve the issue but it still not working:

1. Created a Middleware

   ```
   namespace App\Http\Middleware;

   use Closure;

   class IeFix
   {
       /**
        * Handle an incoming request. Fix session error with Laravel on IE/Edge
        *
        *
        * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
        * @param  \Closure  $next
        * @return mixed
        */
       public function handle($request, Closure $next)
       {
           $response = $next($request);
           $response->header('P3P', 'CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
           return $response;
       }
   }
   ```

   2. Added the class to the application's global HTTP middleware stack like below.

      `protected $middleware = [
              \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
              \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
              \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
              \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
              \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
              \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
              \App\Http\Middleware\IeFix::class,
          ];`

      But I still get same error on IE and Edge? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: The solution you applied should work. 

Could you see with dev tools whether the header is actually being send?

Comment: I have checked @matiit. I can see the headers in Firefox but when I check on Edge and IE, I can see the header being sent. what exactly could be the problem.

Comment: For IE 11 and Edge, I get internal server error - HTTP500

Comment: If you have 500 then check your webserver logs to see what actually happened.

Comment: Hi @matiit, I've checked my webserver log and is okay so what can be the problem?