# Duplicate Cookies in IE / Edge with Laravel 5 (TokenMismatchException)

Tags: internet-explorer-11, session-cookies, laravel-5.3, microsoft-edge, php-7

We have developed a website in Laravel 5.3, but only IE/Edge browsers have problem submitting forms (TokenMismatchException).

I tried some ways to fix it like this: 
[TokenMismatchException in Edge and IE 11 with Laravel 5 App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38998153/tokenmismatchexception-in-edge-and-ie-11-with-laravel-5-app).
However, **P3P policy is no longer supported by IE11/Edge on windows 10.** 
[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt146424(v=vs.85).aspx)

I found the problem is that IE11/Edge stores duplicate cookies with the same key name (as string) although $_COOKIE stores only one for each keys (as array).

For example,

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'] = "laravel_session=aaaaa; laravel_session=bbbb"
$_COOKIE = array('laravel_session' => 'aaaaa')
```

I used a basic web middlewares such as

```
'web' => [
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
],
```

**Basically, laravel request tries to use the value in $_COOKIE, but sometimes it is not the right one.**

In the case, laravel fails decrypting the value (MAC is invalid error occurs in EncryptCookies middleware), so $request->cookies for the key becomes null, and TokenMismatchException is thrown in VerifyCsrfToken middleware.

Does anyone know when IE11/Edge stores duplicate cookies for the same key and how can we avoid it?
I cannot find a specific way to happen the problem, but it often happens in IE/Edge.

Here is some more references that may be related to this issue:

- [Subdomain issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40169160/session-regenerate-id-doesnt-work-in-ie11-edge)
- [IE protected mode + SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658620/ie-protected-mode-ssl-login-no-cookie-for-non-ssl-pages)
- [IE protected mode cookie storage?](https://superuser.com/questions/1083415/ie11-where-are-cookies-really-stored)
- [Apache issue？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371328/are-duplicate-http-response-headers-acceptable)